# How to compile the Zlib source code using Cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, zlib

I'm trying to use the zlib library in a Visual Studio project I'm writing in C++ but I'm not quite sure how to compile it. I'm running Windows 7 and the source has a makefile so I figured I'd just download Cmake to compile it. Cmake ran perfectly fine with no errors (but 13 warnings) but now I'm left with what can be seen in the image below. What is my next step to compile the code? I figured Cmake would compile it since I had to specify Visual Studio when running Cmake. When trying to open the project files (which is what Cmake yielded) and attempting to compile the source that way, I get a weird access denied error. So yeah, have I gone about this process wrong?

[Here's what I see after running Cmake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0FCD.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

CMake is a high-level build manager, it produces a low-level build process files.

You choose to use Microsoft Visual, so it output MSVC project files (`.vcproject` and `.sln`). Next step is to open those files with Visual as you did.

> So yeah, have I gone about this process wrong?

No you haven't. That weird access denied error must be investigated though.

Comment: I can only answer your question literally. Give us more details about the error you ran into and I'll update my answer.

Comment: I feel very relieved knowing that I went about it the right way. This is what I see when I try to compile it. It's weird though because ALL_BUILD is a folder inside of Debug but the only thing inside ALL_BUILD is another folder named ALL_BUILD.tlog
This is the error I get when I compile though: 
https://i.imgur.com/Jfn63NS.png

Comment: It turns out that that folder is set to read-only and windows won't let me change that. I don't get any errors when I try but when I check to see if it worked, it's evident that it didn't

Comment: You can't run the ALL_BUILD target. It is not an executable. It's meant to be dependent on all projects in the solution that need built. So if you compile the ALL_BUILD target you compile everything needed for the package.

Comment: When I press the run and compile button, it automatically tries to compile starting at the ALL_BUILD. Is there a setting that I need to change?

Comment: The output picture showed that you tried to Debug instead of compile. You can't run the ALL_BUILD target so there is nothing to debug. You can switch the startup project in Visual Studio to "example". I expect that to be an executable.

Comment: I usually just click on "Local Windows Debugger" to compile and execute.Setting "example" as the startup project caused it to compile and execute correctly. Is that what I need to do to get the library files? I now have the files pictured below, am I all set or was that just an "example" and there is something else I should do? https://i.imgur.com/RAO52v4.png .
The reason I'm not sure is because I expected there to be a big change in the structure of the folder. In the examples I found online of people using zlib, they referenced the zlib.h file from a folder named "include" which I dont have

Comment: ***I usually just click on "Local Windows Debugger" to compile and execute.*** That is the problem. ALL_BUILD is not something you can debug. From the Build menu you can select compile on this type of target.

Comment: ***referenced the zlib.h file from a folder named "include" which I dont have*** You need to build the install target (again this will not execute so don't try to debug). However that may fail if you did not change the install location when you configured with CMake. The reason is the default install location is likely c:\Program Files. However your OS may prevent you from installing at that location (writing to C:\Program Files needs an OS elevation for a modern windows OS).

Comment: Haha I feel pretty silly now. That all makes perfect sense and now everything looks like it does in the example. Thanks for walking me through that, I definitely learned a lot. Out of curiosity, what's the purpose of compiling and executing the example?

Comment: It probably tests some feature of the library or gives the user a starting example code for the user to begin writing `c++` code that uses the library. I am experienced with `CMake` not really how to use this particular library with `CMake`. However with `CMake` most libraries behave the same way.

Comment: The only problem I'm having now is that I can't compile my test file. The compiler is telling me "LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _gzopen" but under the project properties -> C/C++ I have included the zlib directory in "Additional Include Directories"  and in Linker I have included the "lib" folder found within zlib, also for Additional Library Directories. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: You need to include the libraries directly in your linker settings. Not just the folder containing the library.

Comment: I decided to experiment with the code I found at the link below and I noticed that the creator was able to use the zlib library without including a single .lib file. How can this be possible?

http://www.vilipetek.com/2013/11/22/zippingunzipping-files-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, zlib does have the solution file included. It's in

> contrib\vstudio\vc14

Try again compiling with that.

Comment: When I try to compile with that, I get errors saying that it's not able to find files such as zconf.h. Should I put the solution files on in the main directory where all the .c and .h files are?

Comment: Hmm that's weird. Mine compiles just fine. What's your VS version? Have you extracted all the file?
P/s: Since zlib is a C library, you might want to install the Universal CRT SDK before compiling